# Why does my Python multiprocessing result not append on callback?

Tags: python, multiprocess

I can't seem to figure out why my results are not appending while using the multiprocessing package.

I've looked at many similar questions but can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. This my first attempt at multiprocessing (as you might be able to tell) so I don't quite understand all the jargon in the documentation which might be part of the problem

Running this in PyCharm prints an empty list instead of the desired list of row sums.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
import timeit

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 1000))


def add_these(numbers_to_add):
    added = np.sum(numbers_to_add)
    return added


results = []
tic = timeit.default_timer()  # start timer

pool = Pool(3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for row in data:
        pool.apply_async(add_these, row, callback=results.append)


toc = timeit.default_timer()  # start timer
print(toc - tic)
print(results)
```

EDIT: Closing and joining pool, then printing results within the if name==main block results in the following error being raised repeatedly until I manually stop execution:

RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase. This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

```
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...
```

The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Code to reproduce error:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
import timeit

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 1000))


def add_these(numbers_to_add):
    added = np.sum(numbers_to_add)
    return added


results = []
tic = timeit.default_timer()  # start timer

pool = Pool(3)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for row in data:
        pool.apply_async(add_these, (row,), callback=results.append)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(results)


toc = timeit.default_timer()  # end timer
print(toc - tic)
```

Comment: So you've launched some processes that are going to append to `result` at some point in the future - and then you print out `result` immediately, without waiting for those processes to do anything.  You should call `pool.close()` followed by `pool.join()` before trying to look at the results.

Comment: @jasonharper hmm, if I add pool.close() and pool.join() before print(results), then I get a RunTimeError - "An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

Comment: Everything that involves the pool, including printing the results, needs to be inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.  About the only things that are valid to have outside that block are function definitions

Comment: Okay I put them in the if __name__ == '__main': block but I'm still getting the same error (see edit on question)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a more correct way:

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
import timeit

data = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(5, 1000))


def add_these(numbers_to_add):
    added = np.sum(numbers_to_add)
    return added


results = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        for row in data:
            results = pool.apply_async(add_these, (row,))
            try:
                print(results.get(timeout=1))
            except TimeoutError:
                print("Multiprocessing Timeout")
```

Comment: This answer is not helpful. You should provide description about why and how this code works. Just a friendly advise.

Comment: Hmm, this did seem to work, but when I increase the size of data to size=(500, 100000), I get a TimoutError despite the try except.

Comment: @thposs Try increasing the timeout=2 or higher.

Comment: Ok excellent, that worked thank you. What does the timeout argument represent? Are the units in seconds? Meaning, wait x number of seconds before trying to get the results? - EDIT: ok found the documentation, it does represent seconds.